# How to stick the particle system to a game object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

We've made a flame particle system and we want to attach it to our sword in run animation while the animation is playing.The flame is suppose to be attached on the sword and in run animation sword is moving as expected,but when we the running animation plays the particle system is not attached to the sword, we couldn't find a way to make it attached to sword,it just runs the particle effect but its not sticking to the sword.Is there a way to attach it or do we have to make another game object any advices?

[here is a picture of the particle effect and character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7xXi.png)

[and as i sad here it is its not attached to the sword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRwe0.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are three modes for the [ParticleSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysMainModule.html) set via the property

> **Simulation Space**
>
> Controls whether particles are animated
>
> - in the parent object’s **local space (therefore moving with the parent object)**,
> - in the world space,
> - or **relative to a custom object (moving with a custom object of your choosing)**.

Yours seems to be set to `World` space so no matter where your object moves the particles move related to the world and are not affected by your sword.

So simply set it to the mode you want via the Inspector or set [`ParticleSystem.MainModule.simulationSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-simulationSpace.html) via code to [`ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Local`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Local.html)

> Simulate particles in local space.

and attach the `ParticleSystem` to the sword or one of its children

or [`ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Custom`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Custom.html)

> Simulate particles relative to a custom transform component, defined by [`ParticleSystem.MainModule.customSimulationSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-customSimulationSpace.html).

So in the case of `Custom` additionally set the [`ParticleSystem.MainModule.customSimulationSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule-customSimulationSpace.html) to be your sword. It doesn't need to be attached to it or anywhere nested below it.

Comment: Sword isn't a different game object the player is an game object itself, and i did the animations in Spine2d. Is there an another way to do this?

Comment: Hm is there any chance you can animate a dedicated empty GameObject along with it just to be able to use it as custom reference space?

Answer (score -1):

Try making the particle system a child of the sword game object.

Comment: Answers are not for asking for clarification from the OP. Please wait until you have enough reputation for commenting on questions (afaik 50) and then rather use the comment section. Answers are ment to **answer** the question with a valid solution ;)

Comment: Just needed to construct the sentence a bit differently. Thanks for pointing it out tho.

Comment: This still will make no difference if the system is not set to `Local` mode though ;)

Comment: OP didn't state if it's local so i just placed it out there it may help him.

Comment: Exactly .. what I am trying to say is .. your answer is only half of a solution since it won't help OP nothing to place the ParticileSystem as a child of the sword if the space is not set to Local .. and if the mode is set to `Custom` as mentioned in my answer it doesn't even need to be a child of the sword at all if OP simply references the sword as the `customSimulationSpace` ;) .. Don't get me wrong, do not want to sound picky, but as it stands your answer is more a comment than an answer ;)

Comment: Sword isn't a different game object the player is an game object itself, and i did the animations in Spine2d. Is there an another way to do this?